# Согласование при перечислении

Tags: согласование

Были люди, которым гомосексуальное сообщество подражало - певцам, артистам, писателям - особенно Оскару Уайльду. - пишет Би-би-си.

Может быть, правильно должно быть так:

Были люди, которым гомосексуальное сообщество подражало:(, -) певцы, артисты, писатели, особенно Оскар Уайльд.

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 2):

Корректно: *«Были люди, которым гомосексуальное сообщество подражало: певцы, артисты, писатели (особенно Оскар Уайльд)», — пишет «Би-би-си»*.

Зависимые слова — *певцы, артисты, писатели (особенно Оскар Уайльд)* — управляются главным (обобщающим — *люди*).

Comment: Не уверен, что скобки - лучший варинат. Почему бы не поставить запятую (присоединительная конструкция, см: http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html)

Comment: @М_Г поставить можно, это даже будет по-школьному корректней, но я решил использовать скобки. Это же не противозаконно? http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/162-skobki

Comment: Законно, конечно. Я просто думаю, что запятая лучше, но это недоказуемо (скорее, дело вкуса).